# Is there any guideline for brand logo minimum size on website?

Tags: usability, website-design, gui-design

I have a doubt on logo size of implementing brand/website (widthXheight).
Do we use any guideline for this, I am sure it should not be 8X8, 12X12 or 16X16 pixels.
I need to know what portion should it covered from the container(header or website top pane).

Answer (score 3):

Usually stuff like this is documented inside the companies styleguide.
This varies and is not fixed.

The logo should be perfectly visible, sharp and be in harmony with other elements inside the header.

If you don't have a styleguide then you might as well just check a few known sites and see which size they are using.

I usually go for at least 50 pixel of height, but as i said that does not mean anything.

Comment: To build on this answer, different logos will have different sizing requirements. A detailed logo will need to be shown larger than a simple logo. A landscape (wide) logo may need less height than a portrait logo, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. If this is a startup and required branding, does it has any specific spec for the website logo, despite the fact that the company style guide or still, it depends on the details on the logo and its visibility?

Comment: Yes it depends on the logo itself if there aren't any set guidelines.